# Organizing and displaying list-like result

Tags: list-manipulation

This is most likely a piece of cake for you guys, but it is difficult for me.

Related to a math problem, I examine if `Fibonacci[n]*Fibonacci[n] + <some number K between 1 and 99>` is a prime, and all this for first 1000 Fibonacci numbers only.

For example, this code: (K=1)

```
Select[Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, 1000}], PrimeQ[#*# + 1] &]
```

returns

> {1, 1, 2}

This code: (K=2)

```
Select[Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, 1000}], PrimeQ[#*# + 2] &]
```

returns

> {1, 1, 3, 21, 6765, 32951280099, \
>   971183874599339129547649988289594072811608739584170445, \
>   1082459262056433063877940200966638133809015267665311237542082678938909\
>   }

This code: (K=3)

```
Select[Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, 1000}], PrimeQ[#*# + 3] &]
```

returns

> {2, 8, 3524578, 27777890035288, \
>   2011595611835338993891308327102733537615455242513357158345612749706882\
>   9146295425939723629305572732574726246290673965789878845363842331040064\
>   16432124798818261534841714338, \
>   2949592466076064248964701302014885591673737506156850406413751530665307\
>   5810241060939483954895520932111023343610904846943097162533007651451709\
>   723277579925520157875345780869307228929160}

And this code: (K=99)

```
Select[Table[Fibonacci[n], {n, 1, 1000}], PrimeQ[#*# + 99] &]
```

returns

> {2, 8, 3524578, 6557470319842, \
>   4286863412788815942499567477797350205106309231244244822408841055026686\
>   7672}

I need to get all results from 1 to 99, then count elements of each answer, and display these in the following (or similar) form:

```
   K    number of primes
   1            3
   2            8
   3            6
   .            .
   .            .
  99            5
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fibs2 = Fibonacci@Range@1000^2;
tab = Table[{k, Count[fibs2 + k, _?PrimeQ]}, {k, 1, 99}];

TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None, {"K", "number of primes"}}]
```

(welcome back)

Comment: Hey, you managed to put together the answer faster than the code from the answer (with 99 replaced with 299) executed on my old laptop! That's wizardry! Thanks a lot for the magic!